# Jupyter notebook. IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Tags: pandas, jupyter

Ejecuto correctamente en Spyder, el script siguiente:

```
  # Selección de indicadores para paises de la CEE
def indicadores_CEE (indicator_code, indicator_name, year):
    df_ind_CEE = data[(data.CountryCode == "ESP") | (data.CountryCode == "PRT") | (data.CountryCode == "GBR") |
                      (data.CountryCode == "DEU") | (data.CountryCode == "ITA") | (data.CountryCode == "FRA")]
    # seleccionamos todas las filas en las que el año es >= 2004, y las columnas cuys etiquetas invocamos.
    df_aux_CEE = df_ind_CEE[(df_ind_CEE["Year"] >= ini_year) & (df_ind_CEE["Year"] <= end_year)]
    #year_select = df_aux['Year'] >= 2004

    df_aux_CEE = df_aux_CEE.loc[year_select,["CountryCode", "IndicatorCode", "Year", "Value"] ]
    # pivotamos
    df_analisis_piv_CEE = pd.pivot_table(df_aux_CEE, index=["Year"],columns = "CountryCode",values = "Value")
    df_analisis_piv_CEE.plot(figsize = (12,8));
    # Gráfica
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel("GDP per capita")
    #label the figure
    plt.title(indicator_name)       

    return df_aux_CEE, df_analisis_piv

ini_year = 1975
end_year = 2014
indicator_code = "FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG"
indicator_name = "Inflation, consumer prices (annual %)"
indicator_country = "ESP"

df_aux_CEE, df_analisis_piv_CEE = indicadores_CEE (indicator_code, indicator_name, year)
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo en jupyter notebook me devuelve el error:

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index
>   of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Otros scripts desarrollados en este mismo proyecto, funcionan bien en ambos. La versión de Python es la misma en ambos. Al principio del notebook tengo puesto %matplotlib inline. data es una importación de un fichero csv (560845KB)
¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

Comment: Tu función hace uso de una variable `data` que no aparece en tu ejemplo (supongo que es una variable global). Sin ella no podemos intentar replicar tu problema para ver qué ocurre. No obstante, dices que en spyder te funciona mientras que en Jupyter no. ¿Estarás usando la misma versión de python y pandas en ambos? Veo que intentas crear un gráfico, ¿has puesto `%matplotlib inline` al principiop de tu notebook?

Comment: Otros scripts desarrollados en este mismo proyecto, funcionan bien en ambos. La versión de Python es la misma en ambos. Al principio del notebook tengo puesto %matplotlib inline. data es una importación de un fichero csv (560845KB)